# DataFrame drop column not working

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame `df` with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- car: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Then I do: `new_df = df.drop("person.name")`. I also tried `df.drop(col("person.name"))` The schema of `new_df`:

```
root
 |-- car: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

The schema of `new_df` has not changed. Any idea why?
Assuming I want a final result with (person.age, car), how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to separate the `person` `struct` column into separate columns and then use `drop`

```
new_df.select("car", "person.*").drop("name")
```

If you want `person.age` back then you can *construct* it back as `struct`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
new_df
  .select("car", "person.*")
  .drop("name")
  .withColumn("person", struct("age"))
  .drop("age")

root
 |-- car: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

As @RaphaelRoth has pointed out in the comments below that you can just use

```
new_df.select($"car",struct($"person.age").as("person"))
```

Or even shorter as

```
new_df.withColumn("person", struct("person.age"))
```

**udf way**

You can even do it in `udf` way (is not recommended though) (just for your information)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def removeStruct = udf((p: personOld)=> person(p.age))

new_df.withColumn("person", removeStruct(col("person")))
```

for that you would need two `case classes` though

```
case class personOld(age: Long, name: String)
case class person(age: Long)
```